# Pass qr scan output to search field

Tags: flutter, search, qr-code

Can someone help me how/where i have to change so that the output of _scanBarcode can put into _runFilter where you also can type to search items.

When i type in the search field it works fine but i thought of adding a qr scan function but dont know where to put the result in the _runFilter function.

I thought i had to put it in the scaffold textfield but i guess im wrong.

```
// main.dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:flutter_barcode_scanner/flutter_barcode_scanner.dart';
import 'sql_helper.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      // Remove the debug banner
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        title: 'Floormanager JOOST',
        theme: ThemeData(
          primarySwatch: Colors.orange,
        ),
        home: const HomePage());
  }
}

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  // All Items
  List<Map<String, dynamic>> _journals = [];

  //bool _isLoading = true;
  // This function is used to fetch all data from the database
  void _refreshJournals() async {
    final data = await SQLHelper.getItems();
    setState(() {
      _journals = data;
      //_isLoading = false;
    });
  }
  // This list holds the data for the list view
  List<Map<String, dynamic>> _alljournals = [];
  @override
  void initState() {
    _alljournals = _journals;
    super.initState();
    _refreshJournals(); // Loading the diary when the app starts
  }

  // This function is called whenever the text field changes
  void _runFilter(String enteredKeyword) {
    List<Map<String, dynamic>> results = [];
    if (enteredKeyword.isEmpty) {
      // if the search field is empty or only contains white-space, we'll display all items
      results = _journals;
    } else {
      results = _journals
          .where((item) =>
          item["title"].toLowerCase().contains(enteredKeyword.toLowerCase()))
          .toList();
      // we use the toLowerCase() method to make it case-insensitive
    }

    // Refresh the UI
    setState(() {
      _alljournals = results;
    });
  }

  String _scanBarcode = '';


  Future<void> startBarcodeScanStream() async {
    FlutterBarcodeScanner.getBarcodeStreamReceiver(
        '#ff6666', 'Cancel', true, ScanMode.BARCODE)!
        .listen((barcode) => debugPrint(barcode));
  }

  Future<void> scanQR() async {
    String barcodeScanRes;
    // Platform messages may fail, so we use a try/catch PlatformException.
    try {
      barcodeScanRes = await FlutterBarcodeScanner.scanBarcode(
          '#ff6666', 'Cancel', true, ScanMode.QR);
      debugPrint(barcodeScanRes);
    } on PlatformException {
      barcodeScanRes = 'Failed to get platform version.';
    }

    if (!mounted) return;

    setState(() {
      _scanBarcode = barcodeScanRes;
    });
  }

  // Platform messages are asynchronous, so we initialize in an async method.
  Future<void> scanBarcodeNormal() async {
    String barcodeScanRes;
    // Platform messages may fail, so we use a try/catch PlatformException.
    try {
      barcodeScanRes = await FlutterBarcodeScanner.scanBarcode(
          '#ff6666', 'Cancel', true, ScanMode.DEFAULT);
    } on PlatformException {
      barcodeScanRes = 'Failed to get platform version.';
    }

    if (!mounted) return;

    setState(() {
      _scanBarcode = barcodeScanRes;
    });
  }


  final TextEditingController _titleController = TextEditingController();
  final TextEditingController _descriptionController = TextEditingController();
  final TextEditingController _aantalController = TextEditingController();

  // This function will be triggered when the floating button is pressed
  // It will also be triggered when you want to update an item
  void _showForm(int? id) async {
    if (id != null) {
      // id == null -> create new item
      // id != null -> update an existing item
      final existingJournal =
      _journals.firstWhere((element) => element['id'] == id);
      _titleController.text = existingJournal['title'];
      _descriptionController.text = existingJournal['description'];
      _aantalController.text = existingJournal['aantal'];
    }

    showModalBottomSheet(
        context: context,
        elevation: 5,
        isScrollControlled: true,
        builder: (_) => Container(
          padding: EdgeInsets.only(
            top: 15,
            left: 15,
            right: 15,
            // this will prevent the soft keyboard from covering the text fields
            bottom: MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets.bottom + 120,
          ),
          child: Column(
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
            children: [
              TextField(
                controller: _titleController,
                decoration: const InputDecoration(hintText: 'Title'),
              ),
              const SizedBox(
                height: 10,
              ),
              TextField(
                controller: _descriptionController,
                decoration: const InputDecoration(hintText: 'Description'),
              ),
              const SizedBox(
                height: 20,
              ),
              TextField(
                controller: _aantalController,
                decoration: const InputDecoration(hintText: 'Aantal'),
              ),
              const SizedBox(
                height: 10,
              ),

              ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: () async {
                  // Save new journal
                  if (id == null) {
                    await _addItem();
                  }

                  if (id != null) {
                    await _updateItem(id);
                  }

                  // Clear the text fields
                  _titleController.text = '';
                  _descriptionController.text = '';
                  _aantalController.text = '';

                  // Close the bottom sheet
                  Navigator.of(context).pop();
                },
                child: Text(id == null ? 'Create New' : 'Update'),
              )
            ],
          ),
        ));
  }

// Insert a new journal to the database
  Future<void> _addItem() async {
    await SQLHelper.createItem(
        _titleController.text, _descriptionController.text, _aantalController.text);
    _refreshJournals();
  }

  // Update an existing journal
  Future<void> _updateItem(int id) async {
    await SQLHelper.updateItem(
        id, _titleController.text, _descriptionController.text, _aantalController.text);
    _refreshJournals();
  }

  // Delete an item
  void _deleteItem(int id) async {
    await SQLHelper.deleteItem(id);
    ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(const SnackBar(
      content: Text('Succesvol verwijderd!'),
    ));
    _refreshJournals();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Floormanager JOOST'),
      ),
      body: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
        child: Column(
          children: [
            const SizedBox(
              height: 20,
            ),
            TextField(
              onChanged: (value) => _runFilter(value),
              decoration: const InputDecoration(
                  labelText: 'Search', suffixIcon: Icon(Icons.search)),
            ),
            const SizedBox(
              height: 20,
            ),
            Expanded(
              child: _alljournals.isNotEmpty
                  ? ListView.builder(
                itemCount: _alljournals.length,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) => Card(
                  key: ValueKey(_alljournals[index]["id"]),
                  color: Colors.amberAccent,
                  elevation: 4,
                  margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10),
                  child: ListTile(
                    leading: Text(
                      _alljournals[index]["id"].toString(),
                      style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 24),
                    ),
                    title: Text(_alljournals[index]['title']),
                    subtitle: Text(
                        '${_alljournals[index]["aantal"].toString()} stuks'),
                      trailing: SizedBox(
                        width: 100,
                        child: Row(
                          children: [
                            IconButton(
                              icon: const Icon(Icons.edit),
                              onPressed: () => _showForm(_alljournals[index]['id']),
                            ),
                            IconButton(
                              icon: const Icon(Icons.delete),
                              onPressed: () =>
                                  _deleteItem(_alljournals[index]['id']),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      )),
                  ),

              )
                  : const Text(
                'No results found',
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 24),
              ),
            ),
          ],

        ),
      ),
    floatingActionButton: Stack(
        fit: StackFit.expand,
        children: [
          Positioned(
      left: 90,
      bottom: 20,
      child: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () => _showForm(null),
    ),
    ),
        Positioned(
        left: 30,
        bottom: 20,
        child: FloatingActionButton(
            onPressed: () => scanQR(),
            child: const Text('QR scan')),
            


        )
      ],
    ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After you get the result of the QR-Code, just call the filter method:

```
 setState(() {
      _scanBarcode = barcodeScanRes;
      _runFilter(_scanBarCode);
    });
```

Comment: Thanks.. i did that but when scan a qr i dont see anything happen..

Comment: It works now.. thanks :)